# Why the similarity between these sections from Tchaikovsky and Saint-Saëns?

Tags: history, composers

I noticed that part of [Saint-Saëns' *Africa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa_(Saint-Sa%C3%ABns)) (1891) sounds very similar to [Tchaikovsky's *Concert Fantasia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concert_Fantasia_(Tchaikovsky)) (1884), and was wondering whether they were friends/contemporaries during their lives so would have had the opportunity to share material, or whether they had been inspired by the same source. Or perhaps it's just coincidence?

I haven't been able to find anything about the two together online.

Links to each with timestamp to skip straight to the parts I mean:

- [Tchaikovsky's *Concert Fantasia*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=527Bb9IGZUE&t=1351s)  (22:30)
- [Saint-Saëns' *Africa*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95TVQkyR0zk&t=261s) (4:21)

Comment: [This article on Camille Saint-Saëns](http://en.tchaikovsky-research.net/pages/Camille_Saint-Sa%C3%ABns) from the Tchaikovsky Research website should help, although not to the point of giving a reason for the similarity you noticed.  It looks like they were fast becoming friends since the very first meeting in 1875, even dancing a [*pas de deux*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pas_de_deux) in that visit!

Comment: One similarity of the passage in question is the theme, identified as theme D in *Africa*, notated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Saint-Sa%C3%ABns,_Africa_-_Theme_D.svg).  Since Tchaikovsky wrote the piece first, it's very likely that Saint Saëns simply borrowed the theme after hearing a performance of *Concert Fantasia*.  Or like you said it is possible the theme is from a common source, maybe a folk song?

Comment: Listening to the two reminds me of the incident when Richard Strauss was accused of "borrowing" several motifs from Vittorio Gnecchi's opera *Casssandra* for his own *Elektra*. See [NYT](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/07/arts/music/strausss-elektra-sure-seems-to-resemble-another-work.html) and [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vittorio_Gnecchi). For a detailed analysis and more about "unconscious plagiarism," see "Tebaldini, Gnecchi, and Strauss" by Michael Horwath (Google it for access).